# How can this hinge point be at rest?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

[image]

The given situation is shown in figure, my doubt is that point O must be accelerating but it is not possible.
Where am I going wrong in my method?
Please help

Comment: Can someone help me here?

Comment: The question is unclear to me. Why are you saying that the hinge point $O$ must be accelerating? On your drawing, that point is clearly fixed to the ground.

Comment: Sir, 2 forces are acting along point O, one it's weight (of the small region) and other the external force F by hinge. Further, internal forces can't act here in the direction of perpendicular to rod because of strong law of action and reaction. Thus, at point O rod is having a net force atleast in upward direction because that small weight of that point can't balance the external force F.

Comment: I'm not sure what the "strong law of action and reaction" is. But, if you choose to look at only the tiny portion that is resting on the hinge - if you cut off the other parts of the beam - then you will have to add shear forces (and also normal forces) at the cuts. Those shear forces are internal forces in the beam as a whole. And they point along with the cut surface; so, they point vertically.

Comment: Ok sir, I got this idea of shear force, but what about strong law of action and reaction (it states that internal forces between two particles must be acting along the line joining them, further had this not been the case ,even after force balance we should have a net torque due to internal forces as they might be equal and opposite but are acting at different positions. How can we explain this?

Comment: Sure, the attractive (or repulsive) internal forces act along the line directly between two particles. If that line is tilted, then those internal forces have a vertical component, right? If your hinge normal force $F_0$ and gravity together cause a non-zero net force in one particle, then that particle will start to move. As soon as it is displaced the slightest bit, the line that joins this particle to its neighbour particles becomes tilted. And then the internal forces contain vertical components.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, one final question, does that mean that at the starting of system, the point O is having non zero acceleration?

Comment: Yes indeed. But the duration will be negligibly small. I have added an answer to try to summarise all this. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is a mistake to claim that there are no vertical internal forces acting on the bit of the beam that is resting on the hinge.

If you choose to look at only the tiny particle that is resting on the hinge - if you cut off the other parts of the beam - then you will have to draw a force at the cut that represents the pull that the now removed neighbour particle had. Neighbour particles pull and push with electric forces, chemical bonds etc.

That force from the neighbour particle is internal. And that force may have

- a parallel component (we call that a shear forces; in your case that is a vertical force) and
- a perpendicular component (we call that a normal force; in your case a horizontal force).

As you mention in the comments, that force is indeed along the straight line between the two particles. So, when the beam is horizontal and all particles are equally high up, then the internal force between two particles is horizontal as well with no vertical component. But the particle at the hinge will be pushes at by the $F_0$ at the hinge, whereas the other particles will not. So the other particles of the beam will start falling down, while the touching particle won't. That touching particle is thus pushed slightly higher up than its neighbours.

In that instant, the line between that particle and its neighbour starts having an angle. It starts having a vertical component. So, in that instant it starts holding back to avoid that they separate.

- A soft, elastic material will allow for a lot of slack before that vertical component is large enough to balance it all out. Such a material will bend a lot.
- A hard, stiff material will show an enormous vertical component very, very soon after any slight displacement of a particle happens. Such a material will not bend to any practical degree (it will bend at the micro-scale, infinitesimally little at any practical scale; but it *will* bend).

If you look at a long enough steel beam, you will actually be able to see it bend slightly and not just infinitesimally. You will even see it on glass.

Comment: To me this appears to be a static equilibrium problem where internal forces are not considered. An ideal pin support offers no moment resistance.From a static equilibrium perspective the beam should rotate since the sum of the moments about the pin support are not zero.

Comment: @BobD Agreed. The question here focuses on the sub-system around the contact point, though. So this answer is general and about cutting into sub-systems.

Answer (score 0):

> How can this hinge point be at rest?

For static equilibrium, the only way the beam will not rotate around the hinge (pin) is if the hinge has a counter clockwise moment reaction equal to $mg$. Otherwise you need a downward force to the left of the pin that provides a counter clockwise moment equal to the clockwise moment due to $mg$.

Below is a picture of a practical pin support. Any resistance to rotation would be in the form of friction due to the tightened bolt. In statics, pins are considered ideal, that is, they have no moment reaction. In the picture the hinge approaches being ideal if the bolt is loosened.

As a practical matter, pin supports would not be relied upon to offer a moment reaction for a beam.

Hope this helps.
[image]